# How can i reach GrantUriPermission problem without Open_Document filedialog?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, uri, permission-denied

I want to open a file in an external PDF viewer.
if I call the file with the "OPEN_DOCUMENT" file picker everything works fine.

if I call a a different file directly with hardcoded existing URI without user dialog I don't have permissions.

get this Errors:

> 

```
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10153 does not have permission to content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ANot%2FBar%2Ftest.pdf [user 0]; you could obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2071)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.grantUriPermission(IActivityManager.java:5748)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.grantUriPermission(ContextImpl.java:1935)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.grantUriPermission(ContextWrapper.java:805)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.grantUriPermission(ContextWrapper.java:805)
    at de.temaks.stepbystep.MainActivity.grantPermissions(MainActivity.java:203)
    at de.temaks.stepbystep.MainActivity.oPDF(MainActivity.java:184)
    at de.temaks.stepbystep.MainActivity.my10(MainActivity.java:144)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:441) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7146) 
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7119) 
    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:803) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27533) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7386) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980) 
 Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
    at com.android.server.uri.UriGrantsManagerService.checkGrantUriPermission(UriGrantsManagerService.java:1174)
    at com.android.server.uri.UriGrantsManagerService.grantUriPermission(UriGrantsManagerService.java:767)
    at com.android.server.uri.UriGrantsManagerService$LocalService.grantUriPermission(UriGrantsManagerService.java:1317)
```

I tried to set flags of all files in folder with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE:

```
public void openDirectory(Uri uriToLoad) {
// Choose a directory using the system's file picker.
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);

// Optionally, specify a URI for the directory that should be opened in
// the system file picker when it loads.
intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, uriToLoad);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

startActivityForResult(intent, 3333);
```

}
And in activityRusult tried to set flags for all the files in that folder:

```
            if (requestCode == 3333
            && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // The result data contains a URI for the document or directory that
        // the user selected.
        Uri uri = null;
        if (resultData != null) {
            uri = resultData.getData();
            // Perform operations on the document using its URI.
            Log.i("Verzeichnis ", "gelesen: "+uri.toString());

            //take persist permission for later use
            getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

            int takeFlags = resultData.getFlags()& (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                    | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            ContentResolver resolver = this.getContentResolver();
            resolver.takePersistableUriPermission(resultData.getData(),takeFlags);
            File directory = new File(path);

            Log.i("directory.exists():   ",String.valueOf(directory.exists()));
            Log.i("directory.canRead():  ",String.valueOf( directory.canRead()));
            Log.i("directory.length():   ",String.valueOf( directory.length()));
 
            /*File[] files = directory.listFiles();
            Log.i("Files", "Size: " + files.length);
            Toast.makeText(this,String.valueOf(files.length) +" 

            String[] theNamesOfFiles = new String[files.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {  
                    theNamesOfFiles[i] =  files[i].getName(); 
             }*/
```

This take no effect, because the errors are after that still the same.
Maybe i have the wrong flags?

**directory.exists()  give "true"**

**directory.canRead() give "false"**

I set the flags just to the "Directory tree".
Should i set flags on each file seperatly?

At the moment in test case i build the uri manually (this uri (file) is in the tree i set the flags ). Later a i want to call saved uri's out of database.

```
Uri uri2 = Uri.parse("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ANoten_MVP%2FBariton%2F0018_Wiener%20Elan-Bariton.pdf");
oPDF(uri2);
```

Send the uri to external App:

```
    public void oPDF(Uri myUri){
    Uri uri = null;

    uri = myUri;

    uri.getAuthority();

    String mimeType = getContentResolver().getType(uri);

    Log.i("mime Type ", mimeType);

    //this.grantUriPermission(null, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    Log.i("URI Import",uri.toString());

    String path = uri.getLastPathSegment()  ;//getEncodedPath();
    path = path.substring(path.indexOf(":") + 1);
    Toast.makeText(this, "importiert: " + path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Log.i("READ_REQUEST_CODE 42: "," hier sind die Ergebnisse aus onActivityResult: " );
    Log.i("uri DER: ", uri.toString());

    Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    //target.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3A"+ path), "application/pdf");
    target.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    //Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open PDF using");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    grantPermissions(this,target,uri,true);
    try {
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        // Instruct the user to install a PDF reader here, or something
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Applications found to open pdf", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Still the same Error

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10153 does not have permission to content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ANoten_MVP%2FBariton%2F0010_Laridah%20Marsch-Bariton.pdf [user 0]; you could obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs

How can I get permissions of all files of a folder?
What could I do?

Comment: `target.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");` You are not showing how you build up your uri.

Comment: my uri is existing and correct.

Comment: You should call takePersistableUriPermission() only once.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to build up nice uries for files once you have seen a few obtained with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

But with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT the content provider (or the OS, tell me!) also gives you permission to use that uri. And remembers them!

What you have perceived now with:

> > Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10153 does not have permission to content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ANot%2FBar%2Ftest.pdf [user 0]; you could obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs

Is that you have not obtained a permission to use your uri.

Comment: My uri is correct and existing.

Comment: I need access to all files in a folder (mybay hundreds files).   It is unpossible to open each file in a ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT manually. That's why I'm looking for a solution to get permission for a complete folder and the files in it.

Comment: That is pretty simple. Let the user select the folder with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. You have then permission for all files in it.

Comment: Okay, good to know! Is the permission just in the onActionResult? - or also reachable out of later function's. Also for the external app?

Comment: Pesistant permission taken: For the life time of your app on that device.

Comment: i edited my first post, added 'directory.canRead' in the onResult callback. canRead gives false and the outcommented Code would crahsing the app.  any Suggestions?

Comment: What has your variable 'directory' to do with the uri you obtained for the choosen directory? `File directory = new File(path);`  What has variable `path` to do with the uri for the directory that was choosen? What are you doing? You are not even using the uri of the directory. And you cannot use the File class.